# A vector using NSMutableArray that contains Point2d elements

Tags: nsmutablearray

How can I use NSMutableArray to do something like below done before in C++.

vector  BubblePacking (int _state, vector & _location_points, float _bubble_size);

I have created a Point2D class but I don't know how to make it work as in c++

// -------------Point2D class

```
@interface EVAPoint2D : NSObject
{
    float x;
    float y;  

}

@property float x,y;

-(void)setXY: (float) xVal: (float) yVal;

@end
```

// -------------Point2D implementation

```
@implementation EVAPoint2D
@synthesize x,y;

-(void) setXY:(float)xVal :(float)yVal{
    x=xVal;
    y=yVal;
}

@end
```

now how can I make let objective-C that I need to create a vector of Point2D elements using NSMutable array

thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/)

You have to initialize an NSMutableArray with `myArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.
Then, to add an object, instead of `push_back(myPoint)`, you use `[myArr addObject:myPoint]`.
To access a value, you use `[myArr objectAtIndex:i]` rather than `myVector[i]`.

Also remember to release your point objects after you add them to the array, and release the array after you are done. (Unless, of course, you are using ARC)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this right away. Also how to make the type of the function to be passed NSMutableArray, when using c++ I was able to do something like this. vector<Point2D> myfunction(int a, int b);

Comment: They behave like any obj-c object. For example, to return an array, create a method like `- (NSMutableArray *)myfunctionA:(int)a B:(int)b;` for returning an array.